# HP PSC 1200 Printer Drivers for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I have a HP-G62 laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium x64 and a HP PSC 1200 series All-in-One Printer.

Windows can't find the drivers for the printer and the HP support website says the drivers are already included in windows 7 (which isn't true). Scanning via [Paint.net](http://getpaint.net) does work, its just the printing that isn't working.

Comment: A driver is available in the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewRedirect.aspx?updateid=613110a4-cfcb-474e-ab76-8f1dab3160ed).

Answer (score 0):

To install the printer, go to Devices & Printers. Click on Add a Printer and go through the process. When asked for the printer model, click on Windows Update. That will let you download the driver from Microsoft, and you can then continue with the rest of the installation.

If the printer is USB connected it should start this process automatically when you plug the printer in.